# Raspberry Pi's message in Ubuntu: Pending Kernel Upgrade, kernel version 6.5.0-1007-raspi

Tags: upgrade, kernel, raspberrypi

[image: Pending Kernel Upgrade, kernel version 6.5.0-1007-raspi]

For some reason Ubuntu won't upgrade my Pi to the latest/requested kernel, 6.5.0-1007. No amount of `sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt fullupgrade` will solve it. Did I mention `sudo reboot`? This pi got more boots than my closet!!!

**Do you know how to do it?**

### Extra Info

**sudo apt update**

After running these commands...

- Everything is `InRelease` (mantic)
- All packages Ok. No problems here

**apt policy**

After running these commands...

- Everything is `release a=now`
- Nothing out of the ordinary here

Following the suggestions in the comment section, after running `sudo apt policy linux-image-raspi` I get this:

```
linux-image-raspi:
  Installed: 6.5.0.1007.8
  Candidate: 6.5.0.1007.8
  Version table:
 *** 6.5.0.1007.8 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-updates/main arm64 Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6.5.0.1005.6 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic/main arm64 Packages
```

However `needrestart` is showing this:

```
sudo needrestart -b
sudo needrestart -u NeedRestart::UI::stdio -r l
sudo needrestart -u NeedRestart::UI::stdio -r a
```

With this output

```
NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.6
NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 6.5.0-1005-raspi
NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 6.5.0-1007-raspi
NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 3
NEEDRESTART-UCSTA: 0
Scanning processes...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Pending kernel upgrade!

Running kernel version:
  6.5.0-1005-raspi

Diagnostics:
  The currently running kernel version is not the expected kernel version 6.5.0-1007-raspi.

Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled automatically, so you should consider rebooting. [Return]
```

Effectively confirming that I need to update my kernel to 6.5.0-1007...I think

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494841/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of  `apt policy linux-image-raspi`

Comment: @user535733 when I run `linux-image-raspi` I get `command not found`

Comment: Does your system have GRUB or some other boot loader installed. Check that it loads the latest kernel.

Comment: @jarno How can I check that?

Comment: @user535733 My apologies for not typing the full command. I am learning Linux, fresh off the window. Just updated my question with the output you asked

Comment: "*For some reason Ubuntu won't upgrade my Pi to the latest/requested kernel, 6.5.0-1007*" Not accurate anymore. Your `apt policy` output clearly shows that your installed kernel is 1007. Don't need `apt update` output anymore.

Comment: If you are using GRUB, I think you should be able to see the menu during boot, if you keep SHIFT key down.